# iOS Swift PDFDocument, Turkish Characters Broken Export

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdf-extraction

Problem: Some PDF export string broken Turkish Chars.

Sample.pdf // Orijinal Content “ İzmir, çanakkale, kaş, ırmak, bağlıca, çin”

Example;

```
let document = PDFDocument.init("sample.pdf")
print(document?.string) // Output : zmir anakkale kaş, rmak, b alıca, çin
```

But, some pdf’s (document?.string), show chars (ı,ç,ü,ö,ğ,İ,ş), other some pdf’s not Show turkish char.

How do I solve the problem complex? I've been working for months :/ 
I will grateful if you help me.

Thanks, Mr.Ensar.

iOS Developer